# How to link/attach basic variables to Object properties

Tags: javascript, object

I have a question which puzzled me for a long time. I wonder if there is anyway I can link/attach the basic variable (bool, number, string) to some object's specific property.

For example, `var str = "Hello"`, `var myobj = {value: null}`. When we change the value of `str`, then `myobj.value` will **automatically** change to the same value. For example, if we assign `str="ok"`, then `myobj.value` will also have the value of "ok".

I wonder if there is any possible way to accomplish it? What's more, I know how to do it the opposite way using "setter". For example, changing `myobj.value`, and using "setter", we can **automatically** change the `str`'s value at the same time. But I cannot find a way do it the opposite way.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the opposite of a setter is a getter. Just do

```
var str = "Hello";
var myobj = {
    get value() { return str; },
    set value(s) { str = s; }
};
```

Comment: Thank you...I just found my question is stupid xD(｀・ω・´)

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this method to return the variable's value?

```
var string = "hello";

var myObject = {
  getString: function() {
    return string;
  }
};
```

Check out the pen - https://codepen.io/SkiZer0/pen/Wjzedp?editors=0010